# livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js not working in thickbox.js in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, thickbox

livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js is not working in thickbox in chrome, thickbox is opening but validation not working at all, but it works in ordinary seperate page in chrome,

Note: Thickbox with livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js validation works well in firefox.

While view source i could not find this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsscript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="jsscript/thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsscript/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js"></script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
  var f21 = new LiveValidation('Firstname',{onlyOnSubmit: true });
  f21.add( Validate.Presence,{ failureMessage: "Please enter your first name" });
});
```

even i included this in the page. if any one knows let me get the solution

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems, using X-ara Menumaker in a frame-set:

```
<script menumaker src="meny.js"></script>
```

I tryed to change the:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
```

..it results in the frame is loading, but... without the meny.js-application!

Not much help, but...

REFERENCE: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html

Peter